# help about methodology

Tags: encryption, python

I am a beginner in reverse engineering.

For a challenge I need to reverse a code in python this code use enigma algorithm :
To found the good configuration to decode the enigma code received.

The goal is to found the good configuration the bellow :

```
def create_configuration():
number_of_rotors = random.randrange(3, 6)
rotates_amounts = [3, 5, 7, 11, 17, 19, 23]

result = []
for _ in range(number_of_rotors):
    rotor = "".join(random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, 26))
    rotates_amount = random.choice(rotates_amounts)
    result.append([rotor, rotates_amount])
return result
```

- After analyse I decided to make a bruteforce because I can see a random.choice and it's "impossible" to found exacly the sames configuration as the server who encoded the message. For That I modify this code :
- number_of_rotors is a number between 3 and 6 logically it's will be a loop [3, 4, 5, 6]
- rotates_amounts is all the possibilities numbers for the originally list ([3, 5, 7, 11, 17, 19, 23])

code :

```
def create_configuration(number_of_rotors, rotates_amounts):
result = []
    for i in range(number_of_rotors):
    rotor = "".join(random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, 26))
    rotates_amount = rotates_amounts[i]
    result.append([rotor, rotates_amount])
return result
```

I added The generator function to generate all the possibilities as (i am using itertools): 
  [3,3,3,3,3,3,3],[3,3,3,3,3,5],...

```
def generators():
values = []
val = [3, 5, 7, 11, 17, 19, 23]
for _set in product(val, repeat=7):
    values.append(_set)
return values
```

This part of code also generate randomly ascii list :

```
rotor = "".join(random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, 26))
```

So my questions is :

- I don't know if it's the good approach for this problem ? If people have ideas.

Thank you very much.

Comment: enigma is symmetric you can use the same encypt algo to decrypt also  like enig Hello = VBSEN / enig VBSEN = Hello

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about cryptanalysis and should be posted on Cryptography Stack Exchange website.